# JS download file from the server does not working

Tags: javascript

I am getting from my server a png file. The response looks like this:

```
�PNG

IHDR|�<V� IDATx���w�T����ם^����I�
v[$��J��bL����oL�&єob���K��QEQ���RDzoK���˽�?f�Sd��ǃ���s���;�����s�����������������-��@DDDDDDDDDDDD�
```

When I'm trying to convert it to a blob and download it, the file is empty.

```
  download() {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => this.downloadFile(res.text()));
  }

  private downloadFile(data) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/png'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return url;
  }

this.download(this.config.guid).subscribe(url => {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = "data.png";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `get` is already downloading it, what's the purpose of (and content of) `this.downloadFile`?

Comment: I need to get the user the ability to download the actual file to his computer when he clicks on the link.

Comment: Um...that's kind of what happens if you click a link. Why not just allow them to do that? Return the response with the `Content-Disposition` header `attachment; filename=data.png` and the browser will offer to save it.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* => `.text()`. Whatever is `res`, converting binary data to text sounds wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE11, `fetch` makes it easy to get a Blob for a downloaded resource:

```
fetch(url).then(response => response.blob()).then(blob => {
    // Use the blob here...
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = blobUrl;
    link.download = "data.png";
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
});
```

---

That said: I would just make the link an actual link and return the data with the `Content-Disposition` header set to `attachment; filename=data.png`. The browser will offer to save the file when the user clicks the link.

Comment: And if you need to support IE>=10 `XHR.reponseType = 'blob'` is not so hard either.